# How do you change which app opens when USB is connected?

Tags: usb, my-files

Regarding which app will be opened when I connect a USB ("OTG") device.

How do I change this setting. I do not wish any of the following apps to open:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

(The screenshot shows the situation when I connect a USB flash drive.)

I wish Android stock file manager  ("My Files") to open when I connect a USB flash.

A week ago I got problems connecting USB. Test apps for USB say flash disks are connected but I can not see them.

The only time they work is when Android stock file manager opens on connection. It always used to be like that but now "My Files" only opens automatically, occasionally.

It seems to work better for flash drives that have never been connected before. Somehow some apps have decided that they should open for certain defined USB devices. (I may unfortunately have replied yes to some questions earlier.)

I naturally looked in the application manager. I found a relevant setting for one of these programs but not for the remaining.

It is not practical right now to uninstall the programs or format flash drives.

How do I make stock file manager "My Files" open default when USB is connected?

Thanks

Android 5.0,
Galaxy Note 3

Edit

If someone else gets the same problem I can add this: The best file managers for USB/OTG that work even if Android can not see the flash drives seem to be:

1. Nexus Media Importer ($5)
2. Total Commander OTG plug in ($1)

With a modern good speed USB flash drive these two programs copy files with "reasonably" good speed.

Comment: If that screenshot is what you get to see in those cases: Have you tried tapping the "File Manager" and then the "Always" button (provided that "File Manager" is the one you want)?

Comment: The "File Manager" in the screen shot is not the one I want. The one I want is the Android stock file manager. It is called "My Files". It does not show up.

Comment: @ycc_swe This is doable, to launch your My Files app but there is a slight problem. Do you use USB OTG for anything other than accessing USB drives? If you don't then you can use Tasker or Automate app to listen to the broadcast with action `android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED` and launch your My Files app when done receiving it. It works perfectly as long as I don't go attaching other type of USB peripherals, such as a mouse.

Comment: Thanks. I've downloaded the two apps. I haven't yet understood how to set one of them up to connect "My Files" to the broadcast. / It is definitely worth a try. But I would prefer to do it within the Android system without adding extra apps. If I start My Files manually it will not help the situation. / What is my main problem is naturlly to make the Android system see the USB flash drives. I am not primarily looking for an automated start of My Files. / I just notice that when Android starts My Files automatically my USB flash work. / I don't use other USB than flash drives.

Comment: In this situation, where Android has a problem seeing the USB flash drive, I would like to find the setting to stop all other apps from opening and have only My Files open when USB is connected. That was the original situation. I used USB long time like that and it worked fine. If I get back to that I hope USB will work. / It still works like that when I connect NEW usb drives. But somehow these apps have decided that they should open when my old USB sticks are inserted. I must get rid of that setting. These apps interfere somehow. I just can't uninstall them now. I need them.

Comment: I went one step further. I uninstalled the apps that open when my old flash drives are connected. But it didn't resolve the problem - Now nothing happens when my old flash drives are connected. But when new flash drives (that were not connected a week ago, when problems started) are connected, they work. ("My Files" open automatically and flash drives are seen by the Android system.)/ I need to erase the settings that make my phone recognize these old flash drives and treat them in a way that the system can't see them.

Comment: The problem seems to have almost disappeared by itself! I had problems with three flash drives. Another drive that hadn't been connected for a while, worked though. (I didn't dare test more drives.) / Today all drives except one works. (The faulty one was even formatted (not quick) in std Windows program. But still faulty). I also bought new that works. / One possibility is that the three faulty drives got a write error. The cable feels ok but maybe I change it anyway if connector is loose. / Today all works as before. Android "My Files" (and not the strange ES File explorer free version) ...

Comment: ... "My Files" open. My theory that other file managers take over, seems incorrect, at least as the single cause. Today also the newly installed OTG managers open but all works fine. / I think somehow three of my flash got some strange write error. One file manager had problems deleting files on the faulty one today./ Well. In retrospect it is easy to say "The flash drive is often faulty" :)